# List dependencies injected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

Is there a way to know what dependencies were injected into my Angular module?

```
angular.module('myModule', [
  'ui.bootstrap'
])
.controller('myController', [function () {
  // var dependencies = Magic.dependencies;
  // console.log(dependencies);
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, if you inject `$window`, you can dig for the dependencies, specifically, there exists a `.requires` on your module. To do this, you can either declare your [module](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) as a global `var` so we can find it on our `$window`, in this case, let's call it `app` - or - you can bypass globals and `$window` and call `angular.module('myModule').requires` directly.

- I've added `ngRoute` as well to prove the array of dependencies that will be discoverable.

```
var app = angular.module('myModule',
[
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngRoute'
]).controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
    console.log($window.app.requires) // ["ui.bootstrap", "ngRoute"]
    console.log(angular.module('myModule').requires) // without global - $window not needed
}]);
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/c78shdgn/) - working example

---

Note - If leveraging globals, you can simply call the `window` as such:  `window.app.requires` - without injecting `$window`. However, see the [AngularJS $window docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) to understand why `$window` is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [@salniro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30763311/363701), you don't need globals, or `$window`.

The dependencies are listed on the `.requires` property of [`angular.Module`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module):

```
angular.module('myModule', [
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngRoute'
])
.controller('ctrl', function() {
    var app = angular.module('myModule');
    console.log(app.requires); // ["ui.bootstrap", "ngRoute"]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8vtf6gar/1/

Comment: Zach thanks for your feedback. I have updated my answer with your findings since this was a minor alternative. I appreciate you looking into this as well

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks for providing the answer! Never knew this was possible